# Tutorial for TYPO3 Extension tt_products

Tags: typo3-6.2.x

I'm trying to install a Shop on my TYPO3 v6.2.10. My general Question is, if someone has already set up a shop with tt_products on 6.2 LTS and how i can configure it to use the productcategories as Navigation. (Multilevel) up to 4 subcategories.

Hope you can send me some tipps and tutorials how i can set up the shop.

Best regards
Chris

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At first you must install the extension mbi_products_categories which provides hierarchical categories and as well many categories for each product.

You must enhance the default setup of the file setup.txt in tt_products in order to get more than one hiearchy level shown.

```
conf.tt_products_cat.ALL {
    hierarchytiers = 4
}
```